# Repeat Images under WPF in the manner of CSS

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am thinking to create some backgrounds under WPF UserControl and keep all images as embedded resources.

And what I guess is **to minimize images sizes** and keep 1 pixels width images and just repeat it SOMEHOW like we have it under CSS.

```
background-image: url(http://s11.postimage.org/ufpdknvjz/left.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Is there any approach to do it with XAML?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you want to use an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) and specify the proper [`TileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx). Not sure if you can do just X though...

Answer (score 2):

Use the Stretch property of an ImageBrush

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://s11.postimage.org/ufpdknvjz/left.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <!-- Other content -->
</Grid>
```